# Parse path for any workspace

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, parameters, file-path

I have a model which adds and calculates a new field with a workspace path.
I upload only one layer from database to the model (called "tline"). Parse path can detect only the name and file of this layer, not the whole path to the GDB file which contains this layer. The path can be found only if I add a workspace variable and set the path to database in this variable. So when I set a parameter "Parse type" like "Path" for "tline" layer, model won't work, it just add a new field and says that *"The process did not execute because the precondition is false."*

[image]

How can I find the path to GDB automatically using model builder? It is also important when I have several GDB files that have the same layer "tline" within. I just want to overcome a manual input of GDB file into the model.

Comment: What is the relationship between the model and the tool dialog that you have pictured?  They do not appear to correspond to each other.

Comment: If you have python knowledge you can insert a script to find the path using os.path

Comment: @PolyGeo It has no relationshps, I just want to show that often you need to put a workspace variable and make the path to GDB file manually. I think with some Arcmap tools this process can be simplified.

Comment: @jbalk Unfortunately I have no any knowledge of Py. Moreover, I make this model for several computers with other users, and if I am not mistaken Python script file should be on their computer too to import it properly to the model. I think it'sa bit complicated thing.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what it is that you are asking.  I think when you say `the view (called "tline")` you are meaning a layer called "tline", and wanting to be able to access the source of that layer (presumably a file geodatabase feature class) and then to parse the path of that to get its file geodatabase.

Comment: Is your goal to add the path as an attribute?  This can be executed in a simple script that you can run as a tool.  You can embed the script in the tool so it can be used across different machines.  What path do you want?  The full path like C:\Test\Data\Data.gdb\tline?  Or do you just want the GDB path like Data.gdb\tline?

Comment: @jbalk I need to get a path like "C:\Test\Data\Data.gd‌​b". And how to embed this script wihout any additional files?

Comment: Is that the only purpose of the model, to add the path field and attribute?

Comment: @jbalk I need use this path in other tools which I add to a model, like making buffers, spatial joins etc. Right now I have to manually set the path to workspace variable and use this path in other tools for output layers like %Workspase%\tline_buffer. Instead of that I wanted to simplify it and have something like "%Path%\%File%"\tline_buffer

Comment: I'll look at this tomorrow and see if I can offer a solution.  Thanks for the extra details.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with these additional details.  Potential answerers, who are all volunteers, do not always have time to read the comments on questions.

Comment: And reading this comment **"First make sure you drag-and-drop the input feature class into your model from the Catalog Window or ArcCatalog, and not as a layer from ArcMap's TOC. Otherwise the path property (and extension) can't be retrieved."** made my day and solved a problem puzling me for the last two days - why a new tool I created to add Path field and populate would not populate the path values. A Modelbuilder 'gotcha' that I have not seen explained anywhere else. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After seeing your conservation with @GISGE, though reluctantly, I have decided to put in my two cents. I do not think there is a direct way of getting file path of a layer's data source from given Model Builder tools. However you can use [Calculate Value tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/calculate-value.htm) to get the required parts. Assuming you are **always** going to use LAYERs from your MXD's TOC, the setup below should work.

[image]

The difference here, Parse Path is not connected to your input layer and output_value is a precondition to Add Field to make sure Calculate Value will run before anything. The trick is to input the code very below into this tool as shown below.

[image]

And here is the code:

Expression

`GetPath("%tline%")`

Code Block

`def GetPath(lyr):
    import os
    mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    target=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,lyr)[0]
    return target.dataSource`

**ASSUMPTIONS**

- this works only with LAYERs from your **CURRENT** (the map document which is already open and where your model is open in editing mode) MXD's TOC
- if there are more than two layers with the same name, this will get
  the first instance in the order of display
- it will only work with layers which support [dataSource property](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm#P_GUID-A1071A05-599A-4662-8354-4F676BA87878) (essentially the feature and raster layers are just safe)

Comment: @faih_dur, heeey everything works fine!!! Thnak you so much. However, when I add Calculate field tool, it makes one mistake: instead of `D:\Документы\АСПИР\ОФОРМЛЕНИЕ\test.gdb` it makes `D:\Документы\АСПИР\ОФОРМЛЕНИЕest.gdb` I typed '%Value%' and used Python 9.3

Comment: Try r"%Value%". Also have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63816/python-formatting-path-strings-and-checking-if-a-path-exists.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you drag-and-drop the input feature class into your model from the Catalog Window or ArcCatalog, and not as a layer from ArcMap's TOC. Otherwise the path property (and extension) can't be retrieved.

Then use the expression `'%Value%'` with the `PYTHON` parser in the Calculate Field:

[image]

Make sure your new field is long enough to hold the dataset's path (the default 50 characters might not be enough).

Comment: I don't think `tline` in the asker's case is a dataset like in your answer.  I *think* it is a layer.

Comment: yes, it is a layer, containing in Gdb file.

Comment: A _layer_ (in your display or in memory) is a view, or a representation of a _feature class_ (i.e. a dataset saved on your disc - in a gdb or in a folder). So do you want to access the _layer_ in ArcMap's TOC, or the _feature class_? How are users supposed to use your model?

Comment: @GISGe In this case I need to get an access to feature class, from path of which I need only the path to *.gdb file, not the whole path to feature class. Other users are going to test my model which find roads that are torn by other ones of lower levels (in case someone made a mistake during attribute edition). The model I made is working without mistakes but I think that it would be better not to click hundred times to set a path to base, because there are lots of levels to check. I thought about drag'n'drop function to dialog box of model but it appeared to be impossible in modelbuilder

Comment: If you choose the `PATH` option in the `Parse Path` tool, you will get the path to the gdb (e.g. C:\data\mygdb.gdb). The rest of your comment is not clear to me, sorry.

Comment: @GISGe I've just tested a model you made and here what I've got when select "PATH" type in Parse path tool `The process did not execute because the precondition is false.`

Comment: This is because your input is a LAYER from your Table Of Contents in ArcMap. If you add your input from the CATALOG instead, it works.

Comment: @GISGe that is clear now. I have to work with layer in TOC anyway. Adding class from catalog is not a solution for my task. Drag and drop GDB path from TOC to dialog box in model is can be performed?